# How to check how many passes are needed to sort the elements in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

How to check how many passes are needed to sort the elements in an arraylist by using bubble sort? I have these two methods.

```
public boolean checkInSortedOrder(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakes){
  boolean sorted = true;        
  for (int i = 1; i < quakes.size(); i++) {
            if (quakes.get(i-1).compareTo(quakes.get(i)) > 0){ 
            sorted = false;
        }
}

return sorted;
```

The above method checks whether the arrayList is sorted or not. 
And this method performs the bubble sort.

```
public void onePassBubbleSort(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakeData, int numSorted){
    int j;
    QuakeEntry temp;
  for(int i=0; i<numSorted; i++){
   for( j=0; j<(quakeData.size()-i-1);j++){
         if(quakeData.get(j).getMagnitude()>quakeData.get(j+1).getMagnitude()){
          temp=quakeData.get(j);
          quakeData.set(j,quakeData.get(j+1));
          quakeData.set(j+1,temp);
         }
       } 
      System.out.println("Printing Quakes after "+ i +" pass ");
       for (QuakeEntry qe: quakeData) { 
       System.out.println(qe);
    }
   }

}
```

I know i need to add a counter variable. But bit confused with the code.

Comment: Add a counter variable and increment it each time you are doing passes.

Comment: I know i need to add a counter variable. But i am bit confused with the code. HElp me with the code please.

Comment: @Darpanjbora: The termination condition for the second for loop is the number of passes ( Length - 1, if ArrayList has 4 elements, then passes will be 3, always one less than the total elements ), one needs in this case. What exactly you need to know.

Comment: Why iterate through all data to test if ordered instead of order it directly? 1 time to check and second time to order instead of 1 time to order?!

Comment: @nIcEcOw Yeah it is because of the bubble sort. What I want to know is that for bubble sort we need to run the loop until it is sorted. So, how can i find the minimum number of passes required to sort the ArrayList.

Comment: @Tokazio: I will be having a third method which will use the above two methods to check how many passes are required.

Comment: To know how many pass to do, you must do the ordering or simulate it, then you double the passes... Like @nIcE cOw says, you do the first ordering to 'n-1' and you can count how many exchange you make in the if statement, that will give you how many real passes you made.

Comment: @Darpanjbora: Consider taking a boolean value, set it to `false` in the beginning of a pass, and set it to `true` if swap happens, and at the end of the pass, check to see it's state has changed. If it is still `false`, break out of loops, since the list is sorted now, since no swap took place, hence all elements are in order.

Comment: You can't know if its ordered till the end of the datas.

Comment: @nIcEcOw: Please help by writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can simply use a boolean value, to check how many minimum passes are required to sort a given list, as shown in the code below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BubbleSort {

    private static final int TOTAL_ELEMENTS = 5;

    private List < Integer > numbers;
    private boolean isSorted;
    private Random random;

    public BubbleSort () {
        random = new Random ();
        isSorted = true;
        numbers = new ArrayList < Integer > ( TOTAL_ELEMENTS );
        numbers.add ( new Integer ( 1 ) );
        numbers.add ( new Integer ( 2 ) );
        numbers.add ( new Integer ( 3 ) );
        numbers.add ( new Integer ( 4 ) );
        numbers.add ( new Integer ( 5 ) );
    }

    private void performTask () {
        int pass = 1;
        while ( pass <= numbers.size () ) {
            isSorted = true;
            for ( int i = 0; i <= ( numbers.size () - pass - 1 ); ++i ) {
                System.out.println ( "i: " + i + " pass: " + pass + "[ i ]: " + numbers.get ( i ) + " [ i + 1 ]: " + numbers.get ( i + 1 )  );
                if ( numbers.get ( i ).compareTo ( numbers.get ( i + 1 ) ) > 0 )  {
                    System.out.println ( "Entered if clause" );
                    Integer temp = numbers.get ( i );
                    numbers.set ( i, numbers.get ( i + 1 ) );
                    numbers.set ( i + 1,  temp );
                    isSorted = false;
                    display ();
                }
            }
            if ( isSorted ) {
                break;
            }
            ++pass;
        }
        System.out.println ( "Minimum passes: " + pass );
        display ();
    }

    private void display () {
        System.out.println ( "Array content: " );
        for ( Integer number : numbers ) {
            System.out.println ( number.intValue () );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        new BubbleSort ().performTask ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The location of the leftmost inversion and the location of the rightmost inversion gives you a worst case count of how many times you may have to pass over the array.

Of course, it may be the case that the value you obtain is an overestimation. For instance it may be the case that the array is just as follows, in which case you will think 6 passes will be needed while 1 is sufficient.

```
2 1 4 5 6 8 7
```

However this method never underestimates, and I believe in many cases overestimation may be better than underestimation. After all, you can do this after each pass and when you find no inversions then you can just halt.

A second approach would be actually sorting the array using an in-place **O(nlogn)** algorithm and finding the greatest difference of initial and final indices to declare how many passes are required. However if you are free to use an **O(nlogn)** in most cases that would have been what you would do to begin with. So, I assume simulating the sorting in this way is not an option either.

If there was other knowledge about the data to be sorted, like the range information helping [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), perhaps that may be helpful. For instance if you knew the elements had no repetition and they were in the range [1, N], then you could still simulate the sorting procedure and find out the greatest difference of initial and final indices to use as your number of repetitions. Since you didn't mention such a specific set of extra information, however, that is probably not going to help you either.

In a nutshell, since simulation of sorting and extra information are not available to you, I suggest you use the overestimating method a crude and untested Java implementation for which is given below.

```
public int getNumberOfRepsNecessary(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakes){
    int leftmostInversion=-1, rightmostInversion = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < quakes.size(); i++) {
        if (quakes.get(i-1).compareTo(quakes.get(i)) > 0){ 
            if(leftmostInversion == -1) {
                leftmostInversion = i-1;
            }
            rightmostInversion = i-1;
        }
    }
    if(leftmostInversion == -1)
        return 0;
    return rightmostInversion - leftmostInversion + 1;
}
```